# How to implement RSS feed in our website in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, feeds

Can anyone help me out with steps as how to implement RSS Feed in a node in drupal 7?

Comment: What do you need to import? Nodes? Easiest way is to install views and views rss and build view.

Comment: @Frione:I want to implement rss feed at specific nodes so it can be published ,can you be more precise a show to do it via views also as i am new to drupal .

Comment: Difficult to describe in two words. I don't know maybe somebody post you instruction but I doubt. So here link where you could see example http://confluence.tapcrowd.com/display/dev/Setting+up+RSS+feeds+in+Drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the Feeds module. It deals with all things feeds related. Or if you just want to set up an rss feed check out this tutorial which runs you through the process http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/configure-rss-feeds